# Delete rows that have incomplete value in other column in R

Tags: r

I wanted to delete rows in x1 column that don't appear in EVERY month in another column:
The dataset is as follows:

```
id month  
1 01  
2 01  
3 01  
1 02  
2 02  
1 03  
2 03
```

I want to delete id = 3 from the dataset, since it doesn't appear in month = 02

Im using R
Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can split the dataset and use `Reduce`, i.e.

```
remove <- Reduce(setdiff, split(df$id, df$month))
df[!df$id %in% remove,]

  id month
1  1     1
2  2     1
4  1     2
5  2     2
6  1     3
7  2     3
```

As @jay.sf mentioned, you need to assign it back to your dataframe,

```
df <- df[!df$id %in% remove,]
```

Comment: unfortunately this code is not working properly, when Im checking table(df$month) it has still different values for each month

Comment: @Fendi You probably want to assign it back to your data frame, `df <- df[!df$id %in% remove,]`.

Comment: hmm now I get an error: Error: trying to get slot "id" from an object (class "data.table") that is not an S4 object

Comment: convert your object to `data.frame()`

Comment: could you show me in what line to add it? I tried different combination and still have this problem

Comment: Just do `df <- as.data.frame(df)` and then run the code

Comment: unfortunately still the same error :(

Comment: Use `dput(head(df))` to share your actual data then (Edit it in your question)

Comment: I just added it to description

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(month) == n_distinct(df$month)) %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     id month
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     2     1
3     1     2
4     2     2
5     1     3
6     2     3
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data_hh[, if(uniqueN(month) == uniqueN(.SD$month)) .SD, .(id)]
```

#### data

```
data_hh <- structure(list(id = c(18354L, 18815L, 19014L, 63960L, 72996L, 
73930L), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), value = c(113.33, 251.19, 
160.15, 278.8, 254.39, 733.22), x1 = c(96.75, 186.78, 106.02, 
195.23, 184.57, 473.92), x2 = c(1799.1, 5399.1, 1799.1, 1349.1, 
2924.1, 2024.1), x3 = c(85.37, 74.36, 66.2, 70.02, 72.55, 64.63
), x4 = c(6.29, 4.65, 8.9, 20.66, 8.69, 36.22)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```